# Angularjs angular-timer and $http

Tags: html, angularjs, data-binding, timer, angularjs-directive

I've installed angular-timer. The timer can be started with a predefined start time.
The predefined start time is retrieved from the database.
And that's where I've got my issue.

It works great when I enter the start-time in milliseconds directly in the directive

```
<timer start-time="1404281475637">{{ddays}} days, {{hhours}}:{{mminutes}}:{{sseconds}}</timer>
```

but when I use a variable retrieved within the .success() of an $http call, the timer starts at  00 instead of 1404281475637 (default behavior if the date supplied to the directive is Falsy)

```
<timer start-time="timeStartVariable">{{ddays}} days, {{hhours}}:{{mminutes}}:{{sseconds}}</timer>
```

I think that's because timeStartVariable is undefined when the directive is being "initialised" or something like that... 
I'm just surprised as of why the directive isn't "updated"

I also tried to use this in order to start the timer once the variable has the correct value, with no luck...

```
$scope.$broadcast('timer-start');
```

Any idea on how to make that work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have to modify the directive slightly.

Use [scope.$watch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope) inside your directive to watch changes of timeStartVariable and do stuff when it changes!

Comment: Can you please provide your code? I am having the same issue.